# Retrieving data from customer area wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to put on bold the title from some post on wordpress, I have this piece of code for it:

```
 <?php
    $title_popup = sprintf(__('Uploaded on %s', 'cuar'), get_the_date());
    $file_count = cuar_get_the_attached_file_count($post->ID);
    if(strpos(get_the_title(get_the_ID()),'Garajes Gran')!==false){
    ?>

        <tr>
           <td class="cuar-title">
             <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($title_popup); ?>"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></a>
           </td>
           <td class="text-right cuar-file-count">
             <span class="label label-rounded label-default"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%1$s file', '%1$s files', $file_count, 'cuar'), $file_count); ?>   </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
     <?php
      }
```

And I don't get what I want because all titles appears on black.So what is wrong?. The titles which I have are:

```
 Presupuestos (Garajes Gran Via)    0 files
 Presupuestos (Viviendas)   0 files
 Contratos (Garajes Gran Via)   5 files
 Contratos (Viviendas Gran Vía) 6 files
 Contadores de Agua 0 files
 Estatutos (Viviendas)  1 file
 Estatutos (Garajes Gran Vía)
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the_title(); use get_the_title();

```
<td class="cuar-title">
             <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($title_popup); ?>"><strong><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></strong></a>
</td>
```

Comment: It doesn't work because when I do it, the tittle dissapear. Thanks

Comment: are you echo ing it ?

Comment: like this <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>

Comment: I forgot the echo but it doesn't work because everything appears with bold